# org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported ENVERs

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I just started getting this error when I introduced a composite primary key.   Any ideal as to why?  I have been unsuccessful in trying to figure this out.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported: org.hibernate.type.SerializableType
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addIdProperties(IdMetadataGenerator.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addId(IdMetadataGenerator.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.<init>(AuditConfiguration.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.getFor(AuditConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener.initialize(AuditEventListener.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
```

**Update Edit - 1**

Using Hibernate 3.3.1 (Shipped with JBoss 5.1) along with Spring MVC 2.5.6 and jboss-envers 1.2.2GA.

POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="program_store_rel")
@Audited
public class ProgramStoreRel extends MappedModel implements Serializable
{

  @EmbededId
  private ProgramStoreRelPK psRelPK;

  .
  .
  .
}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class ProgramStoreRelPK implements Serializable
{
  /**
 * Identifies the store that this item belongs to
 */
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="store_id",nullable=false,updatable=true,insertable=true)
  private Store store;

  /**
   * Identifies the program that this item belongs to
   */
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="program_id",nullable=false,updatable=true,insertable=true)
  private Program program;
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: Could you post the offending code, as well as any mappings? Also, it would be nice to know the Hibernate version.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug in this version of JBoss Envers (see [`ENVERS-76`](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENVERS-76)). A similar issue was reported in Hibernate Envers ([`HHH-4751`](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4751)) and fixed in version **4.1.7**.

Unfortunately, the suggested workaround is to avoid composite ids.