# Auditing Embeddable Entity using Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-envers

I am trying to add auditing support using Hibernate Envers to the table where entity relations are stored.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.5 and Hibernate 5.3.10.

Below are my classes:

AuditEntity

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AuditEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "uuid",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(
                            name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
                            value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy"
                    )
            }
    )
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private long createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private long modifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(o instanceof AuditEntity)) {
            return false;
        }

        AuditEntity r = (AuditEntity) o;

        return this.getId().equals(r.getId());
    }
}
```

Role

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.hibernate.envers.NotAudited;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role extends AuditEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotAudited
    private String dontAudit;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.role")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>(0);
}
```

User

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends AuditEntity {
    private String sso;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.user")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>(0);
}
```

UserRole

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
})
public class UserRole extends AuditEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRoleId pk = new UserRoleId();

    public User getUser() {
        return getPk().getUser();
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        getPk().setUser(user);
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return getPk().getRole();
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        getPk().setRole(role);
    }
}
```

UserRoleId

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserRoleId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;
}
```

When I run the application it throws the error below. But when I do not extend UserRole from AuditEntity, the application starts up successfully but without audit columns on the user_role table.

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.ercancelik.hibernate.envers.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addIdProperties(IdMetadataGenerator.java:120) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addId(IdMetadataGenerator.java:200) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:642) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:95) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:297) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported ENVERs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100305/org-hibernate-mappingexception-type-not-supported-envers)

Comment: @C. Weber, I am using newer version of the Hibernate, the bug mentioned in the link you provided was resolved in the older version. Also I am trying to add Audit support to the table which stores the relations. If I remove the the "extends AuditEntity" part from UserRole class, the application starts up successfully but user_roles table do not contains the AuditEntity columns.

Comment: I linked the question mainly because of the mentioning of composite ids and them causing trouble with envers. As far as I can see your UserRole has an EmbeddedId with could be the source of your problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is specifically with how you've mapped `UserRole`. If you look you've defined `UserRole` to contain an `@EmbeddedId` but you  also extend your `AbstractEntity` class which also defines its own identifier based on a uuid.  You simply cannot mix these two concerns.

To be honest, I'm surprised that the mappings you provided actually did not throw an ORM exception to start with rather than you getting all the way into Envers since ORM would have had to parse them  initially where ultimately it should have thrown an exception about how the identifier was being resolved.

As a side note, unless there is a specific business purpose for capturing the who/when an entity was created or modified in the main data tables, you can actually capture that as a part of the Envers revision entity once per transaction in the audit data, which will reduce the data being stored per record.

Take a look at custom revision entities provided by Envers; you can hook in there with a spring-bean and gather whatever information you need using the latest Spring Framework combined with Hibernate 5.3+.